# Render drupal field widget in custom page

Tags: php, drupal-7, widget, field

I have my module called mymodule.

In mymodule.module I have:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['mymodule/ship/%node'] = array(
        'title' => t('Shipment details'),
        'page callback' => '_mymodule_addr',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_VISIBLE_IN_BREADCRUMB,
        'weight' => 0,  
    );
    return $items;
}
```

I want to render the addressfield widget inside the page. Then I want to read form values.
Can you help me?

Comment: i am drupal developer, give me more info about what you want to do?

Comment: I want user add address to a node, but not in the edit form. I want, programmatically, use a custom page to render the form and save informations. I now I can use panels, but I'd like to program it.

Comment: this mean you want to save node path programmmatically?

Comment: no. I have already saved my node, but without address field. Now, I'd like to ask user his address and update my node. I want to render in the page the standard form of the widget "addressfield".

Comment: that is very similar to my needs: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25140/is-displaying-a-working-field-widget-form-on-its-own-possible

Comment: I'll do with panel module and I'll integrate the exported feature with my module.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the Field API:

Within your callback function use:

```
$node = node_load($parameter);
$my_field_value = '<front>';
$my_field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_field');
  if ($my_field_items) {
    $my_field_first_item = reset($my_field_items);
    $my_field_value = $my_field_first_item['value'];
}

return l($my_field_value, 'Link name');
```

Have a look at: [Drupal Field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/7) and find the right function for you.

Also at: [Drupal Examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples) are some useful examples that you might use.

As least, don't forget that you can use a custom .tpl file in your theme where you put custom markup to your field.